# How to override a function inside ngOnInit in jasmine when creating an angular component in TestBed?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, testbed

I have an ngOnInit function that is calling another function inside the same component and I'm testing this component using jasmine test.

I would like to mock the function that is inside the ngOnInit function to prevent the original implementation from executing.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeData();
  }
```

I tried the following implementation in my before each function but this way ngOninit will execute twice:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    testHostFixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHostComponent = testHostFixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(testHostComponent, 'initializeData').and.callFake(()=>{console.log("replacement");});
    testHostComponent.ngOnInit();
    testHostFixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Is there anyway to mock the implementation of the function 'initializeData' before ngOnInit executes for the first time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to spy *before* you create the component. So just move the spy above the creation line.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(testHostComponent, 'initializeData').and.callFake(()=> 
    {console.log("replacement");});
    testHostFixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHostComponent = testHostFixture.componentInstance;

    testHostComponent.ngOnInit();
    testHostFixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Your `ngOnInit()` will have been called twice here as the component runs `ngOnInit()` when it is created in the `TestBed`. If you only want it to be called once. Remove the explicit call `testHostComponent.ngOnInit();`

Comment: This solution does not seem to work on Angular 12. Im currently to  achieve this behavior but this solution does not work - [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72828703/how-to-override-the-default-method-behavior-in-jasmine-unit-test-angular)