# How to override the default method behavior in Jasmine unit test - Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to override the default behavior of a component method in `beforeEach` for my unit tests. I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59740825/13690331) but it results in the following error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for myMethodName()
        Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/x/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.component.spec.ts:102:5)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:126:43)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:371:1)
            at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:134:1)
            at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:204:38)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:219:24)
```

This is how my setup in `beforeEach` looks like:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(component, "myMethodName").and.callFake(() => null);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(XComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

### **EDIT**

I fixed the mistake in the `.spec.ts` file because I was trying to spy on the object before it is instantiated. So it is now like this:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(XComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, "myMethodName").and.callFake(() => null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Now the method is overridden but, it seems that some sort of race is happening before the overriding is taken into account. Because, When I modified the spy function as:

```js
spyOn(component, "myMethodName").and.callFake(() => console.log('######'));
```

the first test being executed does not log anything. However the rest of the tests have the overridden method and hence I can see the log.

Comment: You are spying on component before initialization. Try to put your spy line above detectChanges

Comment: @abellay Thanks i fixed that. But my main question would be still how to change the behavior of a method. Because after all after the component is instantiated, ngOnInit is already called i believe and the method which i want to change is already executed once which cause the tests to crash

Comment: In this case OnInit isn't called before detectChanges, so setting Spy before should make it work. Without more informations I don't know what is an issue now. If you want to change just the return of the method you should set spy in this way:
```spyOn(component, "myMethodName").and.returnValue(null);```
If that won't work, please consider updating your question with current issue